# Searching for specific position of binary file to start reading or writing

Tags: c++

Lets say you have a data file with multiple entries of struct type data

Based on the code number variable of one of the data entries,you are supposed to draw out the remaining variables of the structure.

Or maybe should I try to find the record number based on the scode?
then using the record number to find the size I need to skip from the beginning using seekg

```
char scode[MAX];
Subject M;

afile.open (fileName, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

cout << "Enter Subject code: ";
    cin >> scode;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    cout << endl << endl;
    while (afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&M), sizeof (M)))
        {
            if (strcmp(scode,M.subCode) == 1)
            {
                cout << "Subject code not found" << endl;
                cout << "----------------------------" << endl;
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                afile.seekg(-strlen(M.subCode),ios::cur);
                cout << "Subject Code: " << M.subCode << endl
                    << "Subject Name: " << M.subTitle << endl;

                cout << left << setw(8) << "Task"
                     << left << setw(14) << "Title"
                     << right << setw(7) << "Weight"
                     << right << setw(7) << "Upon"
                     << right << setw(7) << "Mark"
                     << right << setw(12) << "Obtained"
                     << endl << endl;

                cout << setw (66) << setfill ('-') << "-" << endl;
                cout << setfill (' ');

                while (afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&M), sizeof (M)))
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= M.noTask; i++)
                    {
                        cout << left << setw(8) << i
                             << left << setw(14) << M.Task[i].title
                             << right << setw(7) << M.Task[i].weight
                             << right << setw(7) << M.Task[i].fullmark
                             << right << setw(7) << M.Task[i].mark
                             << right << setw(12) << M.Task[i].mark / M.Task[i].fullmark * M.Task[i].weight
                             << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: [std::strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) doesn't have to return `1` if there is no match. It could return any positive or negative value.

Comment: Please post what `Subject` is.  The reason is that `afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&M), sizeof (M))` will not work if `M` is not a POD type.